# Can udev trigger an action upon mount alone?

Tags: mount, udev

Can `udev` be used to trigger an action when an **always-connected** drive is mounted, or is it only useful for hotplugging (as the documentation suggests)?

I want to trigger a script when my always-connected SD card is mounted. This rule, placed inside `/etc/udev/rules.d` looks okay in syntax:

```
KERNEL=="mmcblk0",ACTION=="mount",RUN+="/path/to/script.sh"
```

But the script does not run when the drive is mounted.

Once again, there is **no hotplugging** and the drive is an **SD card** (hence the `mmcblk0` device name).

If `udev` is not appropriate, what else might work?

Comment: I think you should check few things, 1. does your script have `execute` permission? 2. do you see mount action for the drive? if not  refer http://linux.die.net/man/8/udevadm and see what event is spit out by udev when drive is mounted. if it is at startup, does udev starts before drive mounted ?

Comment: I am suggesting to you `udevadm monitor` to see events and then write rule

Comment: Thanks for the useful pointer! Turns out `udev` fires *no* `mount` event, just a bunch of `add`, `remove` and `change`. Will have to find a workaround.

Comment: sumid in this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/25071/how-to-run-a-script-when-a-specific-flash-drive-is-mounted suggest using systemd, not sure if you have systemd or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer seems to be "yes, but". In my case at least, the `ACTION=="mount"` event does *not* fire when my already-connected SD card is mounted, but `ACTION=="change"` does. By running `udevadm monitor -p` I was able to identify a property (`ID_FS_LABEL`, the volume label) to make the rule work:

```
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}="MyVolumeLabel",ACTION=="change",RUN+="/path/to/script.sh"
```

But it turns out that `udev` is not ideal for triggering anything other than short scripts, because they block it while completing. Instead I followed the [advice](https://askubuntu.com/a/679600) suggested by AnkurTank and went with a `systemd` service, which works well.